# Drag / Swipe To Move To Next Menu Item

Tags: jquery, html, css, draggable, swipe

I am trying to build a draggable/swipeable menu, so that when you press and hold down on the current menu item and drag it to the next menu item, or the one after that etc., it triggers a click on the link item and loads that page. I am using WordPress but in the code I have posted below is what is outputted by it.

I have build a basic version using dragDealer.js which works when you click and drag the mouse along each menu item, however I cannot figure out how to trigger the click event on the link.

I have a basic JSFiddle laid out with what I have managed to do so far but I'm looking for some help with how to trigger a click on the appropriate menu items.

https://jsfiddle.net/84xkcdpL/4/

In the version I have currently mocked up the active menu item snaps between each link, but if possible it would be great to have it properly draggable and not snapping.

HTML

```
<div id="bottom-menu-container">

<div class="bottom-navigation-container">

<nav id="bottom-site-navigation" role="navigation">

<div class="menu-categories-container">
    <ul id="menu-categories" class="menu">

        <li id="menu-item-230" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-230">
        <a href="/projects/">Home</a></li>


        <li id="menu-item-228" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-228">
            <a href="/stills/">Stills</a></li>


        <li id="menu-item-227" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-227">
            <a href="/moving/">Moving</a></li>


        <li id="menu-item-229" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-229">
            <a href="/news/">News</a></li>


        <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-231">
            <a href="/print-sale/">Print Sale</a></li>

</ul>
    </div>

<div id="demo-simple-slider" class="dragdealer">
  <div class="handle active">
</div>

</div>

    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#bottom-menu-container {
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 81px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%);
    z-index: 999;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

.bottom-navigation-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 87px;
    z-index: 999;
}

nav#bottom-site-navigation {
    position: fixed;
    width: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

.menu-categories-container {
    margin: 0 -600rem;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-left: 600rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-right: 600rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    text-transform: lowercase;
    height: 90px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#menu-categories {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul#menu-categories {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: justify;
    align-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

#menu-categories li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-categories li a:focus {
    outline: none;
}




#menu-categories li {
    background: url("http://static.wixstatic.com/media/6d3d73_763d8ecc876e47beb006d50fc83e8df5.png_srz_35_35_85_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_png_srz")no-repeat;
    height: 80px;
    background-position: center 16px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 9px;
}

.active {
    position: relative;
    background: url("https://wiki.guildwars2.com/images/b/b4/Black_Dot.png")no-repeat;
    height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -45px;
}
```

jQuery

```
if(jQuery(window).width() >= 640){ //415
    var dragDealer = new Dragdealer('demo-simple-slider', {
      steps: 5,
      snap:true,
      vertical: false,

  callback: function(x, y) {
    var dragValue = dragDealer.getValue();
    console.log(dragValue);
    checkDragValue();
    }
    });
};
```

Link to dragDealer.js website –

http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/

Also I should note that I don't necessarily need to use dragDealer.js to do this. This was simply what I managed to get to work with the problem I was trying to solve. If anybody has any better recommendations I would gladly try them out.

Comment: Here's an image containing what I imagine the drag/swipe interaction to look like – http://imgur.com/hgwnQCk